# Core Animation with an NSView and subviews

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I've subclassed NSView to create a 'container' view (which I've called TRTransitionView) which is being used to house two subviews. At the click of a button, I want to transition one subview out of the parent view and transition the other in, using the Core Animation transition type: kCATransitionPush. For the most part, I have this working as you'd expect ([here's a basic test project I threw together](http://nial.me/TestProject.zip)).

The issue I'm seeing relates to resizing my window and *then* toggling between my two views. After resizing a window, my subviews will appear at seemingly random locations within my TRTransitionView. Additionally, it appears as if the TRTransitionView hasn't stretched correctly and is clipping the contents of its subviews. Ideally, I would like subviews anchored to the top-left of their parent view at all times, and to also grow to expand the size of the parent view.

The second issue relates to an NSTableView I've placed in my first subview. When my window is resized, and my TRTransitionView resizes to match its new dimensions, my TableView seems to resize its content quite awkwardly (the entire table seems to jolt around) and the newly expanded space that the table now occupies seems to 'flash' (as if in the process of being animated). Extremely difficult to describe, but is there any way to stop this?

Here's my TRTransitionView class:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self addSubview:[self currentView]];

    transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];

    [self setAnimations: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:transition forKey:@"subviews"]];
}
- (void)setCurrentView:(NSView*)newView
{
    if (!currentView) {
        currentView = newView;
        return;
    }
    [[self animator] replaceSubview:currentView with:newView];

    currentView = newView;
}

-(IBAction) switchToViewOne:(id)sender
{
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [self setCurrentView:viewOne];
}
-(IBAction) switchToViewTwo:(id)sender
{
    [transition setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [self setCurrentView:viewTwo];
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample project somewhere? It's difficult to visualize what's going wrong.

Comment: Rob, that's totally understandable. I've created a test project at: http://nial.me/TestProject.zip. Try resizing the window a few times before and after transitioning between the views to see the resizing issues mentioned above. I have no doubt this relates to me not explicitly setting the resize and position behaviour of my subviews, but Core Animation is a large topic and I'm quite lost.

Comment: That link is DEAD-SKIS.  Not sexy.

Comment: @ndg Hey, did you ever get this working? If so, it would be great if you could post the solution.